# What's the travel insurance definition of a war zone?

Tags: insurance, terminology, war-zones

Some travel insurance companies have clauses stating that they won't insure travel to a war zone.

What's their definition of this?

The best I could find was Wiki's [list of ongoing military conflicts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_military_conflicts), but that includes places like Colombia, India, Peru, and South Korea, the majority of which I'd be happy travelling to most areas in them, and would get travel insurance for them, as far as I'm aware...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I imagine it would depend almost entirely on the wording in the PDS. If the insurer uses a term like "war zone" they should be defining it somewhere. Otherwise, contact them for clarification on the specific regions you're travelling too.

That said, none of the insurers I've looked at use the term. They only talk about harm caused by war or military activities, often in very similar terms:

[iTrek](http://www.itrektravelinsurance.com.au/assets/pdf/iTrek-PDS-20120725.pdf)

> We will not pay under any circumstance if [...] your claim arises from any act of war, whether war is declared or not or from any rebellion, revolution, insurrection or taking of power by the military.

[WorldNomads](http://www.worldnomads.com/policy_wording.aspx?pid=f36057d4e09f42f6bb1ea3e8a07bc930)

> We will not pay for [...] a loss that arises from any act of war (whether war is declared or not) or from any rebellion, revolution, insurrection or taking of power by the military.

[Bupa](http://www.bupa.com.au/staticfiles/BupaP3/pdfs/MUC0308TV0174__0512%20Travel%20PDS.pdf)

> We will not cover any loss or damage as a result of, or caused by [...] war or warlike activities, invasion, acts of foreign enemies, civil war, revolution, insurrection or act of a military power

Assuming I'm interpreting these correctly, they would still cover you in regions with conflict, so long as your loss/injury/etc wasn't caused by the conflict itself.

You really need to check these details with the insurer themselves though. It doesn't matter what I, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_military_conflicts) or [Smart Traveller](http://www.smartraveller.gov.au/) think, only what you get in writing from your insurance provider.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that each company insurance can probably have their own definition. It is usually part of the policy (in the definitions' portion).

Otherwise, it is probably regulated by the jurisdiction where the insurance company is incorporated, which again - may result in a whole bunch of different definitions.

Bottom line - I would look in the policy for a specific definition, and ask the insurance agent if I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

I think looking at your country's safe-fly list is a good indicator. For Australians we have [Smart Traveller](http://www.smartraveller.gov.au/), where you can see the classification of each country. I'd think that Australian travel insurance companies use that to help determine the danger of travelling to a specific place, and I'd imagine your country would have something similar.